# How to open a LUKS, OTFE .vol?

Tags: linux, cryptography, luks, otf

I feel like this is a dumb question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I have a .vol, LUKS/OTFE.

I know the password.

How can I open it?

This should be simple, but the closest answer I've found involves $ dd to a lo 
--- but that seems to be an excessively complicated answer to what should be a relatively simple problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `cryptmount` is the tool you need.

You can find the man page [here](http://www.huge-man-linux.net/man8/cryptmount.html).

Comment: Definitely missed that one when I was searching.
I found a work-around, and I already deleted the .vol - so I can't confirm this works, but it looks right. 

Also notable, there is a LUKS volume manager for Android!

Comment: There is also FreeOFTE for Windows but you only asked about Linux ;)